# onRequestPermissionResult's grantList is empty

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am asking for a permission. I am getting `grantResults array size =0` can anyone suggest me what is that case if any one faced this scenario ?

```
onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray)
```

Comment: Means you haven't granted any permission.

Comment: This much doesn't explain anything, post the core portions of it

Comment: You might get that if you pass an empty array to `requestPermissions()`, I suppose.

Comment: @piyush if permission not granted in that case it will return permission denied

Comment: @CommonsWare: already checked that , I am requesting permission for contacts read

Comment: If you already granted permission then it should be give you the array size >0

Comment: @ManojPerumarath: I am requesting a permission onStart of activity to read contacts but for any one case inside onRequestPermssionResult my grantPermission array size is zero

Comment: Are you requesting for only for one or multiple permissions ?

Comment: @Piyush: I agree but there is one case I am not getting that case may be its OS or device specific

Comment: Just check inside app info that is your contact permission granted or not?

Comment: @piyush its not in my device captured in crashalytics cannot check

Comment: Then you have to check that. In which device is throwing exception?

Comment: @piyush samsung j7 , os version 6.0.1

Comment: There is only issue that contact permission might not be granted from app. We have also same phone in office @NehaRathore

Comment: Can you post the manifest and the requestpermission code

Comment: code is written inside a fragment extending android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: App downloaded from play store?

Comment: @Piyush yes app downloaded from playstore

Comment: Do you know that you have to add privacy policy before you fetch user's sensitive information ?

Answer (score 0):

This is late reply i know, but if it helps anyone ( like me ) which comes across this.

In call requestPermissions the first argument is the array which in turn is returned to onRequestPermissionResult().
If this is empty then the callback grantResults is empty:

```
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(view.context,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED        ) {
             requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                requestCode)
    }
```

This code  requires the following in the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If it is not found then the array being created and passed to the function is empty, in turn making grantResults empty.

Hope that isn't a confusing explanation and helps someone else out